# about removing question

Tags: support, deletion

I am not sure if this is the right place to put the question here. I accidentally reposted my question.

> **Can one shut down his/her own
>   question?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a "delete" button next to the "link" and "edit" buttons. Click it.

If you have problems, please post the link so the Moderators can look at it.

Comment: alternately flag the post (self-flagging is OK *even for moderators*) for moderator attention

Comment: IT should probably be mentioned that this only works for questions without an upvoted answer, as explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/how-do-you-delete-a-question-that-you-have-posted-on-this-website/7001#comment25635_7001).